# Restoring from Time Machine if NEWER version of OS on MacBookPro?

Tags: macos, restore

The heading is really what I would like to do but don't want to attempt if all the experts out there say this isn't possible. Ok, I will start with the computer to give all information:

- MacBook Pro early 2011
- 10GB memory
- Current OS is High Sierra
- with MS Word, Excel, Little Snitch (awesome program) (This is really what I want moved over; I don't want to have to buy it again as I am not sure where my download file is)

Upgrade OS wanted: Big Sur

I was wondering if it's possible with a Time Capsule - Time Machine backup of High Sierra to restore apps and data no OS to the freshly installed Big Sur?

Comment: Your grammar is a little rough. Are you asking if you can take a backup and a mac with a newer OS than the backup and use the backup to load apps / users / data?

Comment: You can download Little Snitch here: https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/download.html You'll need your licence code to make it work correctly.

Comment: You'll need to buy an upgrade to Little Snitch anyway. v4 won't run on Big Sur & v5 won't run on High Sierra. [A v5 license still allows you to run v4 on older Macs, if you have a family license] MS Office will depend on what version you have. 2011 won't run on Big Sur. 2016 will, but is now EoL.

Comment: A late thought - MBP 2011 won't run Big Sur natively. You would need the micropatcher - see https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/install-macos-old-mac-3654960/

Answer (score 1):

Apps like Little Snitch (and MS Office) install component files in all sorts of locations, and realistically, you're better off using the provided installer. The software may not work properly if one file is missing.

As said in the comments, software that is contemporary with High Sierra or earlier may not work on Big Sur without updates or paid upgrades. More importantly, Big Sur is not compatible with your Mac, though there are ways in which it can be installed.

In more recent versions of MacOS, the OS is installed on a separate disk volume from the 'apps and data'. TM does not backup the OS, so it's easier to backup and restore all your apps and data onto a new OS.